# Conditional query concatenation with rx

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I’m having the following problem. I have a base Object I request from a server that has a property isMember.
If that property is true I want to make requests to Endpoint 1, 2, and 3.
If the property is false I want to make requests to Endpoint 1 only.

I've written a basic example of my usecase below with all relevant classes to 
show the program flow. The relevant part for this question is in UserViewModel::loadData in the comment.

I have no idea how to achieve this with Rx...could you give me any hints how you would do it?

Cheers!

```
interface Controller {

    Observable<BaseInfoDto> getBaseInfo(long id);

    Observable<AccountDto> getAccount(long id);

    Observable<MemberFriendsDto> getFriends(long id);

    Observable<MemberLikesDto> getLikes(long id);
}
```

...

```
class UserModel {

    private final long userId;

    private BaseInfoDto baseInfo;

    private AccountDto accountData;

    private MemberFriendsDto friends:

    private MemberLikesDto likes;

    public UserModel(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public BaseInfoDto getBaseInfo() {
        return baseInfo;
    }

    public void setBaseInfo(BaseInfoDto baseInfo) {
        this.baseInfo = baseInfo;
    }

    // … etc.

}
```

...

```
class UserViewModel {

    private final Controller controller;

    private final UserModel userModel;

    public UserViewModel(Controller controller, long userId) {
        this.controller = controller;
        userModel = new UserModel(userId);
    }

    public Completable loadData() {
        return controller.getBaseInfo(userModel.getId())
            .doOnNext(this::setBaseInfo)
            .toCompletable()
            .mergeWith(loadAccountData())

            // if, after BaseInfoDto arrived, BaseInfoDto::isMember is true 
            // load the following other queries
            // else stop after merging loadAccountData

            .mergeWith(loadFriends)
            .mergeWith(loadLikes)
            .doOnTerminate(() -> {
                // notify data bindings
            });
    }

    private Completable loadAccountData() {
        return controller.getAccount(userModel.getId())
            .doOnNext(this::setAccountData)
            .toCompletable()
            .onErrorComplete();
    }

    private Completable loadFriendsData() {
        // like loadAccountData
    }

    private Completable loadLikesData() {
        // like loadAccountData
    }

    private void setBaseInfo(BaseInfoDto baseInfo) {
        userModel.setBaseInfo(baseInfo);
    }

    private void setAccountData(AccountDto accountData) {
        userModel.setAccountData(accountData);
    }

    // … etc.
}
```

...

```
class UserDetailsView {

    private final long selectedUser;

    private final ThreadManager threadManager;

    private final UserViewModel viewModel;

    public UserDetailsView(long selectedUser, ThreadManager threadManager) {
        this.selectedUser = selectedUser;   
        this.threadManage = threadManager;
        viewModel = new UserViewModel(selectedUser);
    }

    void onViewInstantiated() {
        // lots of stuff happens
        loadUserData();
    }

    private void loadUserData() {
        viewModel.loadData()
            .observeOn(threadManager.getMainThread())
            .subscribe(this::showError, this::bindUserData);
    }

    private void showError() {
        // foo
    }

    private void bindUserData() {
        // bar
    }
}
```

...just to be complete

```
interface ThreadManager {

    Thread getMainThread();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flatMap` based on the `isMember` result:

```
controller
  .getBaseInfo(userModel.getId())
  .flatMap(info -> {
    if (info.isMember()) 
      return endpoint1
            .mergeWith(endpoint2)
            .mergeWith(endpoint3);
    else 
      return endpoint1;
})...
```